Error "MSB4057: The target 'PkgdefProjectOutputGroup' does not exist" when building a VSIX project for C# WinForm Toolbox control
I need to create a VSIX file to register my C# WinForm controls in the Toolbox so that other developers can use my extension. I’ve already written the library, and it contains UserControls with the ToolboxItem(true) tag for displaying in the Toolbox.
I created a VSIX project and added my project as existed proj to solution and to the manifest with the type Microsoft.VisualStudio.Toolbox.Control. However, when I build the solution, I get the error:
error MSB4057: The target "PkgdefProjectOutputGroup" does not exist in the project.

The error occurs in my control project when building the VSIX. I tried adding the recommended line to my project:
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />

But I receive a warning message that this line is ignored because the dependency is already included:
warning MSB4011: "...\Microsoft.Common.props" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "...\Sdk.props (49,3)

I’d like to know what I’m doing wrong. Thanks!
Environment:
VS2022 17.11.2
.NET Framework 4.8
Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK 17.0.32122.339
Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools 17.11.435


Do you see, in the .vsixmanifest file, an Asset defined as Microsoft.VisualStudio.ToolboxControl? The d:ProjectName attribute should reference the alias created in the setup project, where the asset (your library) is added as a ProjectReference (the Name property names the alias). Then the IncludeOutputGroupsInVSIX entry should include PkgDefProjectOutputGroup. In the manifest, you should see the same alias, as a project source, and the path attribute should also include PkgDefProjectOutputGroup -- Your Controls need to have the [ProvideToolboxControl] attribute set

For reference, see VSIX extension schema 2.0 - Placeholder syntax for extension manifests and the .pkgdef generated files

Forgot to mention: it's probably simpler if you import your Control(s) in the VSIX package, using the dedicated Template (Windows Forms Toolbox Control), then replace the content of the sample UserControl with your own. Or, build a NuGet package instead, unless you need MS marketplace support

@Jimi , Yes, I see this one:
        <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsPackage" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="%CurrentProject%" Path="|%CurrentProject%;PkgdefProjectOutputGroup|" />
        <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.ToolboxControl" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="MyControlProject" Path="|MyControlProject;PkgdefProjectOutputGroup|" />
        <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MefComponent" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="MyControlProject.Design" Path="|MyControlProject.Design|" />


I really haven't used the attribute, perhaps specifying it will partially solve my problems. I'll try it.
